# Failed to connect to MySQL Server 8.0.11 after 10 attempts

Tags: mysql

Can any one help me with this error message?

```
Beginning configuration step: Stopping Server
Stopping MySQL Server instance...
Ended configuration step: Stopping Server

Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Beginning configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules
Attempting to delete a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall delete rule name="Port 33060" protocol=TCP localport=33060

Deleted 1 rule(s).
Ok.


Adding a Windows Firewall rule for MYSQL80 on port 33060.
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 33060" protocol=TCP localport=33060 dir=in action=allow
Ok.


Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Ended configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service
Attempting to grant Network Service require filesystem permissions.
Granted permissions.
Adding new service
New service added
Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Beginning configuration step: Starting Server
Attempting to start service MYSQL80...
Successfully started service MYSQL80.
Waiting until a connection to MySQL Server 8.0.11 can be established (with a maximum of 10 attempts)...
  Retry 1: Attempting to connect to Mysql@local:MYSQL with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 2: Attempting to connect to Mysql@local:mysql=MYSQL with user root with no password...
MySQL error 0: SSL Connection error.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 3: Attempting to connect to Mysql@local:MYSQL with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 4: Attempting to connect to Mysql@local:mysql=MYSQL with user root with no password...
MySQL error 0: SSL Connection error.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 5: Attempting to connect to Mysql@local:MYSQL with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 6: Attempting to connect to Mysql@local:mysql=MYSQL with user root with no password...
MySQL error 0: SSL Connection error.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 7: Attempting to connect to Mysql@local:MYSQL with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 8: Attempting to connect to Mysql@local:mysql=MYSQL with user root with no password...
MySQL error 0: SSL Connection error.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 9: Attempting to connect to Mysql@local:MYSQL with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 10: Attempting to connect to Mysql@local:mysql=MYSQL with user root with no password...
MySQL error 0: SSL Connection error.
Failed to connect to MySQL Server 8.0.11 after 10 attempts.
Ended configuration step: Starting Server
```

Comment: You are much more likely to get a response if you concisely describe what you did to cause this. You can edit the question to include the extra detail.

Answer (score -1):

Read the error: `Attempting to connect to Mysql@local:MYSQL with user root with no password... MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`

Sounds like you are attempting to log into the mysql server without root password, of which you did not give more context if the default generated was changed or not. Everything else seems to be successful in terms of starting MySQL up until that point, meaning there is a password set, whether set by you or not, and that is most likely why it is failing.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html) on being unable to log in to MySQL locally.